# How to notify user for the update available?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have developed an application in android and does not want to be published on Google play store, but it will be available on our site. User can download it from the site only. Now my problem is if I am updating the application build how will I notify the user who has downloaded that application . Google play Store takes care of this thing but how to do it at our server end.

Comment: Use push notifications ([GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)) from your server or let the app check for new versions on startup.

Comment: I have an open source update checking and installing library that you can use [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker).

Comment: Setup a service on your server that you will ask from the app upon launch if there is an update or not. If there is, you can ask the user if he wants to download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Let the app check with your server for updates every x days (REST, whatever).
2. Use GCM

Your app will have to inform the user that there's an update and he can download it. For example, create a dialog, if user clicks 'OK', open a browser with the download site.

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes you could go 2 ways with this;

1. On app-start (or in a background service when the app isn't even visible) you could check your site. You can per example put up some little xml/json with the version info and compare that to the currently installed version.
2. Use Push Notifications. ([UrbanAirship](http://www.UrbanAirship.com) is a great and easy way to get you going for free with sending these notifications.